# Kalman Filter implementation to estimate position with IMU under high impacts and acceleration

Tags: filter, signals, signal-processing, kalman-filter

I am trying to implement a Kalman Filter to estimate the position of my arm moving in the sagittal plane (2d). To do this, I have an IMU which as usually done, I use the gyro as input to my state model and the accelerometer as my observation.

Regarding the bias, I used 0.001 for the variances of my covariance matrix of the state estimation equation and 0.03 for the variance of the accelerometer (measurement).

This filter works really well if I move my arm slowly from 0 to 90º. But if I perform sudden movements, the accelerometer makes my estimation move downward and it is not very precise (i'm off about 15º), once I move slowly it works well again. But the response under high acceleration/sudden movement is not good.

For this reason, I've thought of having a variance switch which tracks the variance of the last 10-20 values of my accelerometer angle measurements and if the variance is above a certain level I would increase the variance of the accelerometer in the covariance matrix.

Would this be an accurate approach in a system with very high accelerations? What would be a more correct way to estimate the angle under sudden movements? As I mentioned, the result I get when the accelerometer has low variance is very good, but not when "shaken fast".

Also, I would assume that due to this behavior, the accelerometer's variance does not behave according to a gaussian distribution, but I would not know how to model this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a "Bank of Filters", that is independent filters with different noise levels for the variance, and then compute a weighted average the estimates based on their likelihood[link to a reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4028140_Tracking_multiple_maneuvering_point_targets_using_multiple_filter_bank_in_infrared_image_sequence). You can find several references in literature, during my recent work I discovered [Y.Bar-Shalom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Bar-Shalom) has documented such an approach.

In scientific terms what you are describing is an *adaptive-stochastic state estimation problem*΄ long story short there exist methods to change the modelled measurement noise on-line depending on performance indications from the filter.

All the best,
D.D.
Denmark